# How to export a table into the open office spreadsheet (.ods file) through C#.net?

Tags: c#, openoffice-calc

I want to create a .ods file throught C#.net and also want to export tables,images into it.
Is there any solution for that?

Comment: +1 @kostasch. If you want Ferrari go to its show room...

Comment: @Neon-X +1 :) That's the solution! You save my day!!!!

Comment: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL_example_2.. I referred this.. Here they are inserting a cell table.InsertCellAt(2, 3, cell1); If I want to insert a cell next to it e.g table.InsertCellAt(2, 4, cell2); But that cell is coming somewhere else in the next row of the spreadsheet.So I am not able to display a table due to this problem..Do you have any solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

All OpenDocument's is just a couple of XML-files, that are packed into zip-archive and named with different file extensions. It's hard, but possible to write this documents with just only standard XMLWriter/ZipFile classes. Format specifications are [open to anyone](http://www.opendocumentformat.org/developers/).

But there are many packages that simplifies and abstracts this process. Take look on [Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/) and [AODL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AODL/) NuGet package's at least.